# iOS: How to set/reset UIScreen.main.brightness correctly

Tags: ios, swift

For a client app I need to set the screen brightness to max and reset it when the user leaves the screen or closes the app.

So I save the system brightness, set my custom brightness and reset it to system brightness in `viewWillDisappear` as well as `applicationWillResignActive`. In `applicationDidBecomeActive` I set the brightness back to the custom value if there is any.

It works like a charm until the device is locked. When the app resumes I set my custom brightness but `UIScreen.main.brightness` won't change, it just ignores any input from then on. The behavior is intermittent. Sometimes it happens after the first lock, sometimes after the 5th.

Is there a "correct" way of doing this? It's probably not the best feature of the app, but my client wants to achieve the same behavior as Apple Wallet.

Edit: I‘m using Xcode 11 and iOS 13.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Dissasemble PassKitUI using Hopper.app (free) to see what they do (they use privateframeworks). There is PKBacklightController class + BrightnessSystemClient (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness). Path /Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/

Comment: what iOS  and xCode version are you working on ?

Comment: Sry i forgot, i‘ve added that to the description